# Exposing classes inside modules within a Python package directly in the package's namespace

Tags: python, wxpython, namespaces

I have a wxPython application with the various GUI classes in their own modules in a package called `gui`. With this setup, importing the main window would be done as follows:

```
from gui.mainwindow import MainWindow
```

This looked messy to me so I changed the `__init__.py` file for the `gui` package to import the class directly into the package namespace:

```
from mainwindow import MainWindow
```

This allows me to import the main window like this:

```
from gui import MainWindow
```

This looks better to me aesthetically and I think it also more closely represents what I'm doing (importing the `MainWindow` class from the `gui` "namespace"). The reason I made the `gui` package was to keep all the GUI stuff together. I could have just as easily made a single `gui` module and stuffed all the GUI classes in it, but I think that would have been unmanageable. The package now appears to work like a module, but allows me to separate the classes into their own modules (along with helper functions, etc.).

This whole thing strikes me as somewhat petty, I just thought I'd throw it out there to see what others think about the idea.

Comment: Seems like you're just asking for comments, not really asking a question... which is not really right for StackOverflow.  (Though for what it's worth, I see this sort of thing done frequently and I don't think there's anything wrong with it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is a quite common pattern and I think it is also *the* reason why you can include things inside `__init__.py` files.
As a confirmation, just grep for import statements in `__init__.py` files, and you will see that it is widely used in both standard library and common packages.

Comment: You're right. I just looked at wxPython's `__init__.py` file and they do the same thing.